# Что означает ... (троеточие) в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, типы

Увидел следующую конструкцию:

```
class BadStatus(Exception):
    ...
```

Что она означает? Есть ли отличия от:

```
class BadStatus(Exception):
    pass
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Ellipsis Object` или `...` - это литерал встроенной константы (`Ellipsis`). 
 Типа есть `True`, `False`, `None`, `...` .

`...` можно использовать там, где у нас пустое тело класса или оператора (вместо `pass`),

т.е. можно сказать пока здесь пусто, но продолжение следует или потом напишу.

```
>>> ...
Ellipsis
>>> type(...)
<class 'ellipsis'>
>>> bool(...)
True
```

Comment: Можно ещё добавить, что эллипсис тоже является синглтоном, как и `None` и проверять равенство ему лучше через оператор `is`. `if a is ...: ...`.

Comment: Это то же самое, что и `pass`? В чём отличие?

Comment: @hedgehogues это не тоже самое, но в вашем случае `...` можно использовать там, где у нас пустое тело класса или оператора (вместо pass),

Comment: @hedgehogues, отличие в том, что `pass` - это оператор, его например нельзя передать как параметр функции. А `...` можно, т.к. это значение.

Comment: @hedgehogues, `...` возможно использовать как какую нибудь другую константу (или определенную переменную, или выражение без побочного эффекта) - например `if a>7: 3` тоже не будет ничего делать.

Comment: @MarianD выглядит как оверхед и запутывание логики.

Comment: @hedgehogues, по моему это выглядит как отсутствующие, ни кем объяснение логики, **почему** возможно вместо `pass` применить  `...`. Разве я ошибаюсь и кто-то уже до меня объяснил?

Comment: @MarianD вместо `pass` можно записать любую константу (к примеру `None`). `...` можно использовать в срезах, также как и `:`

Comment: босс сказал https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2008-January/011793.html Некоторые люди думали, что было бы мило иметь возможность писать неполный

и пусть это будет синтаксически правильно. пеп 3100 пункт 16 выполнено*